# How to access arrays with HTTP Get call in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How to get access to arrays data by requesting HTTP GET call with headers in 
nodeJS. I am getting undefined error when I am trying to call the 3rd party 
services. I make HTTP GET call with two headers.
**This is response from HTTP GET call.**
Here How I can access to "description".

```
{
"dotdList": [
    {
        "title": "From ₹ 10,299",
        "description": "Haier 181 Single Door",
        "url": "https://dl.flipkart.com/dl/home-kitchen/home-appliances/refrigerators/pr?sid=j9e,abm,hzg&offer=nb:mp:07de369c12&affid=fstlistgm",
        "imageUrls": [
            {
                "url": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/800/j2z1fgw0/refrigerator-new/m/j/c/hrd-1813bms-r-3-haier-original-imaeu7gzwfskmxfx.jpeg?q=90",
                "resolutionType": "default"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/200/200/j2z1fgw0/refrigerator-new/m/j/c/hrd-1813bms-r-3-haier-original-imaeu7gzwfskmxfx.jpeg?q=90",
                "resolutionType": "low"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/400/400/j2z1fgw0/refrigerator-new/m/j/c/hrd-1813bms-r-3-haier-original-imaeu7gzwfskmxfx.jpeg?q=90",
                "resolutionType": "mid"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/800/j2z1fgw0/refrigerator-new/m/j/c/hrd-1813bms-r-3-haier-original-imaeu7gzwfskmxfx.jpeg?q=90",
                "resolutionType": "high"
            }
        ],
        "availability": "LIVE"
    }
]
```

}

How to access to description.

**Here is my actual code**

```
var request = require('request');

    request({
        url: 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/offers/v1/dotd/json',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Fk-Affiliate-Id':'XXXXX',
            'Fk-Affiliate-Id': 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    let dataFs = JSON.parse(body);
                    let titleN = `${dataFs["dotdList"][0]["title"]}`;
                    console.log("error in fun");
                    sendTextMessage(sender, titleN);


                }else {
                    console.error(response.error);
                    console.log("else error");
                }
            });
```

Part 2.**This is another Response JSON**
How Can I access objects from array. here I am making HTTP GET call to another url to get JSON data. below is the reponse data.

Where I am not able to access to array of data. I need to access offer_name

```
[
{
    "featured": "0",
    "exclusive": "0",
    "promo_id": "P74192",
    "offer_id": "180",
    "offer_name": "Dominos.co.in CPS - India",
    "coupon_title": "Garlic Bread & Dip free",
    "category": "Food & Beverage",
    "coupon_description": "TnC: Valid on Saturday",
    "coupon_type": "Coupon",
    "coupon_code": "NET09",
    "ref_id": "src=vcommission&utm_source=Vcommission&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_term=paid&utm_campaign=OLOHome",
    "link": "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=180&aff_id=36792",
    "coupon_expiry": "2017-08-12",
    "added": "2017-08-01",
    "preview_url": "https://pizzaonline.dominos.co.in/",
    "store_link": "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=180&aff_id=36792",
    "store_image": "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/180/dominos.jpg"
}
```

]

Comment: Please edit your answer with better formatting / description of what you are trying to ask. What is the first code block for? What is the third block from/how are you getting it? Etc.

Comment: I update my question @Michael Fedora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answering your questions

#### Part 1

You already access the data's title via `dataFs["dotdList"][0]["title"]`, and you can access the description the same way: `dataFs["dotdList"][0]["description"]`.

#### Part 2

This one is quite similar to your old one. You  should be able to access the fields you want via `responseData[0]["offer_name"]`.

## Explanation of Response objects, arrays, etc.

In your responses you get an **array object**, which you can tell by having **values surrounded by brackets (`[ /* data */ ]`)**. To access values within an array, you use the **access operator**, like so: `arrayValue[0]`, where `0` is the *key* or *index* of the object you are trying to fetch.

In both of your questions you are trying to access the first (and only) object within the array, and thus you can short cut that by using the `0` index of the array, i.e. `responseData[0]`.

Within those arrays, though, you have **objects**. JSON Objects specifically (as is given to you by the HTTP GET request) can have fields with values which can be a string (`"string"`), number (`0`), or a boolean values (`true` or `false`). You can access the *fields* of an object by either accessing them using the **dot operator** (`object.field`) or by using the access operator, but with specific *key* (`object["field"]`). Using the access operator is especially useful if your field's key uses a space or number.

Putting those things together we can figure out your questions quite easily:

`dataFS` is an object, and we are wanting to access the elements underneath the objects in the array called "dotdList". Thus, we can access the list via the access operator (`dataFs["dotdList"]`), then access the first (and only) object via using the 0 index (`dataFs["dotdList"][0]`), and lastly accessing the fields we want by either using the dot or the access operator (`dataFs["dotdList"][0]["description"]` or `dataFs["dotdList"][0].description). If you need to do this multiple times, it is recommended to store the object in a variable, i.e:

```
 var dotd = dataFs["dotdList"][0];
 console.log(dotd.description) // got description!
```

The second part is also quite easy to figure out; you get back an array, you want the first object, and then you want to access the field: thus, access the first object using the 0 index (`responseData[0]`) and then access the fields you want (`responseData[0].offer_name`).

**Always check to make sure what you are trying to access is there (i.e.the array itself in #1 and the objects within the array in both). If it isn't, your code will start throwing errors!**

Comment: thanks you very much Michael Fedora. thanks for explaining in  details

Comment: Where @BaniNaveen ? You'll have to replace "responseData" with your correct variable name.

Comment: then How to show data in json output  {
                 "title":"titleN",
                 //"image_url":"dod_imagesurl",
                 "subtitle":"dotd.description",